# The tweets I'm collecting from tweepy won't save into the CSV file?

Tags: python, linux, csv, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to do a social data science research paper and all I'm trying to do right now is download some tweets and put them into a CSV file. Every time I do this though, the script executes but the CSV file is empty when opened:

```
import tweepy
import csv

consumer_key=""
consumer_secret=""

access_token=""
access_token_secret=""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)


search_words = "leftists -filter:retweets"
date_since = "2021-01-18"

# how does this algorithm determine what tweets are printed?

tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=search_words, lang="en",since=date_since).items(100)

# open and create a file to append the data to
tweets = str(tweets)
csvFile = open(tweets+'.csv', 'a')
# use the csv file
# loop through the tweets variable and add them to the CSV file
with open('tweets.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=tweets,count=100,lang="en",since=date_since, tweet_mode='extended').items(10):
        print (tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text)
        csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text.encode('utf-8')])
        csvFile.close()

print ("Scraping finished and saved to "+tweets+".csv")
for tweet in tweets:
    print(tweet.text)
```

Comment: When using `with` there is no need to to close the file manually. You can remove `csvFile.close()`

Comment: There is a problem when you read tweet,in the line tweets= tweepy.Cursor........... I get this <tweepy.cursor.ItemIterator object at 0x0000028D3303A048>.

Comment: Your code is opening 2 `.csv` files,  and I don't understand why. It is also closing one of the files the first time through the `for` loop. And in neither case does your code specify the path of the file. I suspect the file is being written, but not where you expect to find it. This is of course a guess. Checking the timestamp on the empty file will confirm it. The current directory, where the file is being written in the absence of an explicit path, is very often not the directory where you Python code resides.

Comment: @BoarGules How do I specify the path of the file in this script?

Comment: As in `C:\Users\username\Documents\Tweets\tweets.csv` or `~/tweets/tweets.csv` depending on your platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this different way:

```
import xlwt

book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
sheet1 = book.add_sheet("Sheet 1")

counter = 0
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=tweets,count=100,lang="en",since=date_since, tweet_mode='extended').items(10):
    sheet1.write(counter, 0, str(tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text.encode('utf-8')))
    counter += 1



book.save("trial.csv")
```

Comment: I tried this. But now I keep getting the message 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'created_at''